# Finding number of subgroups of order 3 in an abelian group of order 24

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

**Problem**

Find the number of subgroup of order 3 in an abelian group of order 24?

**Attempt**
Let $n_3$ be the number of subgroup of order 3 . Then by **Sylow's theorem**
$n_3|8$ and $n_3 \equiv 1mod 3$. From this we can tell that $n_3$ can be 1,4 or 8. 
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be an abelian group with $|G|=24=2^3\times3$ and $H$ be a $3$-Sylow subgroup.  Let $n$ be the number of $3$-Sylow subgroups. Then by the Sylow theorem we know $n\equiv 1\mod 3$ and $n|[G:H]$ i.e $n|8$.  Thus $n$ can be $1,2,4$ or $8$, but $2$ and $8$ are not congruent to $1\mod 3$ so we can rule those out.

Now all $3$-Sylow subgroups are conjugate and in an abelian group every subgroup is normal,  it thus follows that there is exactly one subgroup of order $3$.

Comment: sir, How is it possible that 2 and 8 are congruent to 1 mod 3? Also n=4 is congruent to 1 mod 3

Comment: Should be "not congruent"

Comment: sir, why do we cancel n=4? Also I think using the following theorem we can prove it, i.e., for two finite subgroups H and K of a group, define the set $latex HK={hk:h\in H, k\in K}$. Then $latex |HK|=|H||K|\|H \cap K| $. Is it right? Thank you

Comment: All Sylow subgroups are conjugate.  A subgroup is normal if and only if it is the only subgroup in its conjugacy class.  In an abelian group every subgroup is normal.  Therefore, there is exactly one 3-Sylow subgroup.